# How can I create Spring 3 projects using Spring tool suite that duplicate projects created using maven and converted to Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I want to learn spring and I am using using the Spring tool suite because I have faced some issues creating projects using eclipse. I want to study using Mkyong's spring [tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/). If you check this [Hello world](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-hello-world-example/) tutorial, You will notice that he creates projects suing the mvn command. And then he converts them using the "mvn eclipse:eclipse" command. I want to create projects using the STS IDE to insure that everything will work using Spring and maven that are included in the STS IDE. Would you please help me ?

Comment: Just import the project as maven project or do this-> "New->Other->SpringSource Tool Suite->Spring Template Project->Spring MVC Project"

Comment: After I import it as a maven project, I use Run As -> Maven clean then to execute it I use Run As -> Java Applicaion. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, correct(Provided you have maven installed)